# usermod: group 'sudo' does not exist in CentOS

Tags: centos, command-line, sudo, yum, administration

I want to grant a user sudo access.

I suppose mainly I want to grant privileges to install software, and am not quite sure how to this in CentOS:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-in-centos/

wheras in Ubuntu the option, at least as I [recall](https://askubuntu.com/q/2214/847449), is:

`sudo adduser foo sudo`

to add user foo to sudo.  I'm also curious as to why this isn't available in CentOS -- perhaps it's not fine grained enough?

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ sudo usermod -aG sudo rdegamma
usermod: group 'sudo' does not exist
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The group in CentOS isn't called `sudo`. It's call `wheel`.

As root:

```
usermod -aG wheel rdegamma
```

You then need to run `visudo` and uncomment the below line in the sudoers file if you haven't already:

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Have the user start a new shell session to enter their password for `sudo`.